# how to merge or join two dataset without column name by pandas, I use right_on and left_on but shows key error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

There are two dataset,after I using

the first one:data_df like that:

```
          0      1      2      3      4      5
0  sample_0  0.592  0.000  7.215  6.620  0.000
1  sample_1  0.000  0.000  9.950  1.175  0.000
2  sample_2  1.683  3.660  6.097  7.681  0.000
3  sample_3  1.267  0.000  3.914  6.469  0.000
```

the second one:labels_df like that:

```
   sampleid Class
0  sample_0  PRAD
1  sample_1  LUAD
2  sample_2  PRAD
3  sample_3  PRAD
4  sample_4  BRCA
5  sample_5  PRAD
```

I want merge two dataset by same sample name and delete sample_4 and sample_5 row in label dataset, so I tried this:

```
merge_df = pd.merge(labels_df, data_df, left_on='sampleid', right_on='0', how='inner')
```

but it shows the error:

```
Exception has occurred: KeyError
'0'
```

So how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `0` for select numeric column `0`, `'0'` is used for string column, `how='inner'` is by default, so should be omited, also for remove duplicates is used [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
data_df = data_df.drop_duplicates(0)
labels_df = labels_df.drop_duplicates('sampleid')

merge_df = pd.merge(labels_df, data_df, left_on='sampleid', right_on=0)
```

Comment: Another question is, for example, in first row:0      sample_0  PRAD    sample_0  0.592  0.000   7.215  6.620  0.000, how to delete the duplicated sample_0?

Comment: @4daJKong - You can use `data_df = data_df.drop_duplicates(0)`

Comment: Thanks for your reply again, but it didn't work...you mean use drop function before merge right? no matter what, thank you, I have find the answer

Comment: @4daJKong - hmm, it is weird, it should be. Problem is not remove duplicated rows?

Comment: Yes, I want to remove the duplicated column :) in merged dataset, so how to..

Comment: I mean the column  'sampleid' and '0'

Comment: I mean there are two column 'sample id' and 0 both show same infomation, I want to only keep one column in the merge dataset, is there some parametter can be add in the merge method to solve it?

Comment: @4daJKong - I think the best is change data sample and add expected output, [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), because still not understand what need.